# How to convert a list of Strings to a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, linkedhashmap, collectors

I have a list:

`private List <String> list;`

I want to convert it to a LinkedHashMap (to preserve order), such that the first two values in the map are a LinkedHashMap entry and so on until the list is a LinkedHashMap:

`private LinkedHashMap<String, String> linked;`

This is what I have come up with. Admittedly I am new to the Collectors implementations so bear with me:

```
            linked = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Function.identity(),
                        String::valueOf, //Used to be String::length
                        LinkedHashMap::new));
```

this is giving me an error on the LinkedHashMap constructor line:

`Cannot resolve constructor of LinkedHashMap`

This is an example of what the list may look like:

```
zero
test0
one
test1
two
test2
```

and what I want the Map to look like:

```
zero:test0
one:test1
two:test2
```

Thanks

Comment: `String::length` return `Integer` not `String`

Comment: Did you mean to declare `linked` as `Map<String, Integer>`?

Comment: Can you please give examples of what you want the LinkedHashMap to look like for different input lists?

Comment: I meant to declare Map<String, String> @ernest_k

Comment: please see OP @dnault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you complicate your code, a simple loop in your case solve the problem :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
    linked.put(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1));
}
```

[Quick, Ideone demo](https://www.ideone.com/c1DKmp)

**Outputs**

```
zero:test0
one:test1
two:test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed [merge function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-):

> a merge function, used to resolve collisions between values associated with the same key, as supplied to Map.merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)

But to fill map with your expected values using stream api you can use `forEach` method and [`IntStream::iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) from java9

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linked = new LinkedHashMap<>();

IntStream.iterate(0, n -> n < list.size(), n -> n + 2)
        .forEach(i -> linked.put(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1)));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. You're right, im missing the merge statement. How do i do that for <String, String>?

Comment: Hi thanks again. What is the error, `Operator '+' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>', 'int` it's not permitting lambda expressions in combination with mathematic operations ?

Comment: No, it's by itself. I get an error for the two mathematic operations 

`n -> n < list.size() //Bad return type in lambda expression: boolean cannot be converted to in`

AND

`n -> n + 2 // Operator '+' cannot be applied to '<lambda parameter>'`

Comment: @dk40149 method `iterate` is available from java9

Answer (score 0):

This my attempt with java 8.

```
   IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .mapToObj(index -> {
                    if (index % 2 == 0) {
                        return new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(list.get(index), list.get(index + 1));
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            )
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue));
```